# Proving a sequence is a Cauchy sequence from other theorems

Tags: cauchy-sequences

I would like to know if this is an acceptable proof. I have the following statement

> Show directly that a bounded, monotone increasing sequence is a Cauchy sequence.

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence that is bounded and monotone increasing. Then, by the Monotone Convergence Theorem,  $\{x_n\}$ converges. Furthermore, by the Cauchy Criterion, we know that every convergent sequence is a Cauchy sequence and so we are done. QED

Does this work?

Comment: This is not what "show directly" means.

Comment: In general, when asked to prove “directly” it means using the basic definitions.

Comment: $L=\sup_n x_n$ is an upper bound, and you can find $n$ such that $L-x_n$ is as small as you like.

Comment: Thank you very much! But does my argument make sense if they were not asking me to ''show directly''?

Comment: For a direct argument, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566635/show-that-every-monotonic-increasing-and-bounded-sequence-is-cauchy?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L=\sup_{n}x_{n}$, for $\epsilon>0$, find some $N$ such that $L-\epsilon<x_{N}\leq L$. As $\{x_{n}\}$ is increasing, $L-\epsilon<x_{N}\leq x_{n}\leq L$ for all $n\geq N$. In particular, $|x_{n+p}-x_{n}|=x_{n+p}-x_{n}=x_{n+p}-L+L-x_{n}\leq L-x_{n}<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$ and $p=1,2,...$

Answer (score 0):

Start here.  Put $s = \sup_n x_n$; show that $x_n \to s$.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/911420)

Comment: He is looking for a hint, not for someone to give away the shop.

Comment: But the question says "Prove directly (...)". I think this means "without using the fact that it is convergent."