# Prove that $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ is a Cauchy sequence

Tags: cauchy-sequences, eulers-number-e

I have to prove that ($\mathbb{Q}$,d) is not a complete metric space with a counterexample; so, I have to find a sequence which approacches to an irrational number and must be a Cauchy sequence. I thought to $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ but I'm not able to prove is a Cauchy sequence. Can you help me?

Comment: I think you mean that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a $\textbf{complete}$ metric space. Not an answer, but there are definitely easier sequences if you just want to show $\mathbb{Q}$ is not complete.

Comment: You can prove that it is increasing, by induction, and bounded by $3$ by bounding it with $1+1+2^{-1}+2^{-2}+...$. You will also need to [prove that the limit is irrational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_e_is_irrational).

Comment: Aaaah! You just want to prove that there exist a sequence that converge to an irrational number? It's quite easy to prove that Newton's method for zeros applied to the function $f(x)=x^2-2$ converges near $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Pick any irrational number and apply decimal approximation: e.g. $2,\ 2.7,\ 2.71,\ \dots\to e$.

Comment: @podiki thank you very much for the report. I'll edit the text.

Comment: @Boxwood I'd like to find the value of $n_0$: $|a_n-a_m|<\varepsilon\ \forall{n,m}>n_0$. That was my doubt!

Comment: @R.W. Prado I'd like to prove this particular sequence! I know there are other sequences which are easier to prove, but I was trying for this xD.

Comment: So ...  I would prove that the sequence is increasing and bounded to prove it. Any sequence of points that is increasing and bounded is Cauchy.

Comment: @R.W.Prado Mmmh... but can I prove it? It doesn't approach in $\mathbb{Q}$, so the statement of the "property" is not satisfied

Comment: Without referring to the real numbers, you could follow this proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566635/show-that-every-monotonic-increasing-and-bounded-sequence-is-cauchy

Comment: The goal of proving that a sequence is Cauchy and the goal of obtaining an effective computation of the $n_0$ appearing in the $\exists n_0$ of the definition of Cauchy sequence are two different goals. The latter would solve the former, but it is not the only way. Proving that a real sequence is monotonic and bounded implies that it is Cauchy.

Comment: Since you have asked for me who to prove that any increasing and bounded sequence is Cauchy, I would ask you, have you already proved that  Euler's number is irrational?

Comment: A proof can be found here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler%27s_Number_is_Irrational. Now, you are left with a lot of exercises. 1) Prove that $(1+1/n)^n$ is increasing and bounded; 2) prove that any sequence of this type is Cauchy; 3) Prove that the sum $\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}1/i!$ converges to the limit, if exists, of $(1+1/n)^{n}$; 4) To prove that the limit of $\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}1/i!$ is irrational. Any of these steps are quite hard, and you are only trying to prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a complete metric space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a complete metric space, then there are much easier sequences you can utilize than $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$. For example, consider the sequence

$$a_n=\frac{\lfloor 10^n \sqrt{2}\rfloor}{10^n}$$

This sequence converges to $\sqrt{2}$ since

$$\sqrt{2}-\frac{1}{10^n}=\frac{10^n\sqrt{2}-1}{10^n}\leq a_n\leq \frac{10^n\sqrt{2}}{10^n}=\sqrt{2}$$

but we also have $a_n\in\mathbb{Q}$ for all $n$. Since $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational we are done.

---

EDIT: Here is a proof that a sequence is convergent if and only if its Cauchy.

Suppose that $a_n\to L$ and let $\epsilon>0$ be given. By definition, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $|a_n-L|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. But then for $n,m\geq N$ we have

$$|a_n-a_m|=|a_n-L-a_m+L|\leq |a_n-L|+|a_m-L|<\epsilon$$

Now, suppose that $a_n$ is Cauchy and let $\epsilon>0$ be given.

Part $1$: Convergent subsequence

From the definition, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $|a_N-a_n|<1$. This then implies that for all $n\geq N$ we have

$$a_N-1<a_n<a_N+1$$

and therefore for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

$$\min\{a_1,a_2,...,a_{N-1},a_N-1\}\leq a_n \leq \max\{a_1,a_2,...,a_{N-1},a_N+1\}$$

This implies that $a_n$ is a bounded sequence. Then by the [Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) we may conclude that $a_n$ has at least one convergent subsequence. Let us denote this subsequence by $a_{n_k}$ and let its limit be

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} a_{n_k}=L$$

Part $2$: Entire sequence converges

Now, let $\epsilon>0$ be given. By definition, there exists $N_1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $k\geq N$ implies $|a_{n_k}-L|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Additionally, there exists $N_2\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $N_2\leq n\leq m$ implies $|a_n-a_m|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Now, choose $N=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$ and let $l$ be the smallest natural such that $n_l\geq N$ and $a_{n_l}$ is a member of the convergent subsequence. Then for all $n\geq N$ we have

$$\bigg||a_n-L|-|a_{n_l}-L|\bigg|\leq |(a_n-L)-(a_{n_l}-L)|=|a_n-a_{n_l}|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

(the first step in this equation is the [reverse triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality)). This then implies

$$0\leq  |a_n-L|<|a_n-L|-|a_{n_l}-L|+\frac{\epsilon}{2}\leq \bigg||a_n-L|-|a_{n_l}-L|\bigg|+\frac{\epsilon}{2}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$$

(since $|a_{n_l}-L|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$). We conclude that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L$$

Comment: Ok, it's clear, but how do you prove that $a_n$ is a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: Added EDIT for Cauchy if and only if convergent